# Change the navigation bar back to default, when using a Push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

Basically, I change the appearance of the navigation bar like this:

```
// Disable the shadow image
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

// Add the blue line
UIView *blueLine = [[UIView alloc]init];
[blueLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor borderBlueColor]];
[blueLine setFrame:CGRectMake((self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width - 120) / 2, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 1, 120, 1)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:blueLine];
```

However, I just set the custom appearance to only one of the view controllers. When I use a push to segue to another view controllers, it seems that all of them are applied in this custom appearance. But I would like the other navigation bar to change to default appearance. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use appreance proxy

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[YourVC class], nil]addSubview:blueLine];
```

Comment: @MikeZhu where have you placed it ?

Comment: I place it at the AppDelegate file.

Comment: I solve it in another way, which is set "isHidden" to the UIView

Comment: okay or u might set in viewWillAppear and remove in viewWillDisappear